# Unable to download latest hyperledger fabric binaries

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When running the command: `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s` provided on the hyperledger page, I get the following.

```
Clone hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples repo and checkout v1.4.4
Cloning into 'fabric-samples'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4427, done.
remote: Total 4427 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 4427
Receiving objects: 100% (4427/4427), 1.61 MiB | 2.81 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2179/2179), done.
Note: checking out 'v1.4.4'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at bc72f3e Remove Stalebot

Pull Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 1.4.4 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v1.4.4/hyperledger-fabric-darwin-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v1.4.4/hyperledger-fabric-darwin-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz: Unsupported scheme.
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'hyperledger-fabric-darwin-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz'
rm: hyperledger-fabric-darwin-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz: No such file or directory
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 1.4.4 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

Not sure if this is due to the latest MacOs Catalina 10.15.2 update or something to do with the hyperledger fabric project itself?

Has anyone run into the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Man, I just can't win on this one. We used to use `curl` to download the artifacts in the script, but I recently changed it to use `wget` as lots of users experienced broken connections and it was meant to help alleviate that pain. But it seems `wget` has an issue (in some versions) with URL's rendered using variables. Can you try this one instead, which is the commit prior to me switching it to `wget`:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/977ed80d3f3b4fe42dfb8f04cc93a92ab75b709e/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s`

Comment: This command finally let me install v2.0.0 `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/977ed80d3f3b4fe42dfb8f04cc93a92ab75b709e/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't seem like an issue with your MacOs.I think you should try below curl command mentioned in the [Hyperledger fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html) for getting the binaries, fabric latest images and fabric samples.

```sh
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s
```

Here you can get the latest production release binaries or if you want a specific release.
You can also find an in-depth explanation of fabric binaries in the same documentation.

Comment: That is what I am complaining about! I can get the fabric samples with the commands in the documentation, but the binaries do not install!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me I had to install wget first with brew install wget, then used the curl to get the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

try with root

```
 sudo -i
```

and then `curl -sSL Hyperledger binary -s -- 1.4.1 1.4.1 0.4.15`
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to download the tar file separately from the github repository mentioned in the shell script (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh) and extracted it, and then removed the pull binaries part from the the same shell script and then was able to run it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter these types of errors while executing ".sh" shell script files, you could actually get a look into the script file, always the error message will be an echo statement for the else block, so if you take a look at the if block and try to execute the statements in if block, you could precise where the error has occurred. In this case, here what it is doing is trying to download the release from the URL [https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v${VERSION}/${BINARY_FILE}](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v$%7BVERSION%7D/$%7BBINARY_FILE%7D)
But if you simply try to get into the URL https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download
you could actually find that page is not even existing and it's a 404 error. The script that you are executing is outdated.

This is an updated install script with the same end result as the existing script, but with an improved syntax. This script adopts the positive opt-in approach to selecting the components to install. The original script is still present at the same location :

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/main/scripts/bootstrap.sh| bash -s
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue but for Ubuntu and the reason was that I had a space in the directory name. The install script doesn't handle that.

Answer (score -2):

better you use this command

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s
```

its directly install fabricbinaries and images

Comment: So you've just given me the same command that I'm complaining about.

Comment: i am saying that your installing in ios right . you getting error with curl better u try another in the place of curl